# NIkon D5300 Flash problem plus getting different images with the same settings

Tags: nikon, flash, exposure

I have two problems with my Nikon D5300 recently that are driving me crazy.

The first problem is when I take pictures, focusing on the same object, I keep getting different images: one is too bright, and when I take a picture again is too dark, and when I take picture again is good.

I'm in Manual mode using the same settings for all the pictures. For example the shutter speed is 1/6 sec, aperture is f/5.6 and the ISO is 200 in a room with good light.

The second problem is the flash does not go off all the time, using manual mode or Auto mode with the same settings as above. I uploaded the pictures so you can have a look.

I'm using built in flash, and the flash mode is Fill Flash

[image: first manual mode image (overexposed)]
[image: second manual mode image (correctly exposed)]

Comment: The usual reason exposures vary like that is because you have turned Bracketing on, and forgot to turn it off.   See the manual index, bracketing.

Comment: If you are certain you are in fill flash mode and manual, and certain you are waiting for the flash to charge, and if then the flash is not firing at all, I think it may be broken.  As I read the 5300 manual it should always fire.  I would skip auto and spend time in manual/fill and make sure it works there consistently.  Also, what metering mode are you in (matrix, center weighted or spot).  Spot can cause that, e.g. hitting the black cap onetime and the bed another).

Comment: Community - This is a new user, who posted basically everything we needed to get started helping them out and even followed up, share an upvote liberally!

Comment: @WayneF  Bracketing is always off.

Comment: @Linwood Metering mode is Matrix. when I'm using manual mode, the flash goes off but not all the time out of Ten pictures for example fires only on Six pictures

Comment: I think your camera is broken if it is going off in manual/fill mode only some times.  I do not have that camera but as I read the manual in that mode it should always fire.

Comment: @Linwood that's what I think as well.

Comment: i generally always try to click without flash to get less over expose.

Comment: Did you find the issue or got it repaired from Nikon? I am thinking it will be better to buy a new camera than paying money to Nikon. Have the same issue which started after using external flash

Comment: Did you guys find the issue or repaired? I am finding it difficult to pay Nikon $300 than buying a new camera

Comment: What kind of lighting are you under? Flourescent or some other type that flickers? Or incandescent or natural lighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to put some closure to this, at least until the OP finds out for sure, I'm going to propose the answer: the camera is broken and needs repair.  The OP has tried shooting in manual mode with the flash set to always fire, and observed that the flash does not fire.  If so that indicates a malfunction in the flash somewhere, which while not necessarily the cause of the bad exposures, is certainly a good candidate and should be eliminated first before further research.

Comment: @Linwood I have managed to find out what is causing the bad exposure the pop up flash in my Nikon is not functioning properly , when I compared my Nikon D5300 with an other Nikon d5300 , the flash in my Nikon is firing only once compared to the other Nikon which I could see that the flash is firing twice its like a pre-flash and an other flash then the picture is displayed on the screen. does anyone have a solution on how to fix this as I can't send it to Nikon because they are asking for $300 which I think is ridiculous or will a speed light flash work fine  ?

Comment: Check setting E1 in the menu, and make sure you are set to TTL.  In TTL it should be firing the pre-flash, but in M it will fire a fixed strength without pre-flashes.  I also thought you said it was not firing at all at times?

Comment: @Linwood sometimes flash fires sometimes it doesn't fire ,I'm talking  when Im on manual mode not auto mode which is supposed to  fire all the time ,i checked the setting it is set to TTL not manual. like you said it always  fire a fixed strength without pre-flashes even when its set to TTL .

Comment: Then it still sounds broken, unless someone knows of another setting that might defeat TTL?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you, same camera and exactly the same problem, mine started after I tried an aftermarket hot shoe flash adapter, I did use a pixel brand hot shoe adapter because I wanted to use a sony flash on a nikon, needless to say the flash did not work, all the pictures were highly overexposed and the camera went crazy after that, sometimes the flash does work properly and sometimes it is severely underexposed and others severely overexposed, some people say it could be the "flash power board" but i did not pursue a repair because the price was too high, instead I decided to use a compact external flash, Ihope this information helps you.